# How do I pass a php variable from a view to another view in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table which consists of user data. I have created a view in which I am able to view the user's name and on clicking on the name I am expecting to view the detailed info of that particular user. Could you please guide me through the issue? It would be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question your requirement is not clear.
Am replying specifically to this comment of yours :

*Yup right. I have a table which consists of user data. I have created a view in which I am able to view the user's name and on clicking on the name I am expecting to view the detailed info the user. Could you please guide me through the issue? It would be a great help.*

When the user clicks the hyper link , pass the user-id to the link.
Now , write a controller for this route where you get the user details using the user-id and pass it to the view.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So, is there any need of sessions here?

Comment: There are many ways to do it , but the easiest is you can attach the id to your route and get it in your controller. From the docs :  [basic links](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests) `Route::put('user/{id}',` Controller :` 'UserController@update');     public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }`

Comment: But how do I attach an id to the route in a view?

Comment: <a href= "my-url-link/ . {{$userID}}">

Comment: I messed up the formatting of my second comment. It should look like this: `Route::put('user/{id}', 'UserController@update');`   ` public function update(Request $request, $id) { // }`

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy! I will try it out and get back soon.

Comment: I don't see a problem if you are planning to get $user by calling some function from inside the view. However in case you are passing in the $user model into the view, i think you will have to pass it like this : `return view('greeting', ['userId' => $user->id']);`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to share a variable between more than one view, you can easily use the `share` method on the facade. There is actually a whole section in the docs about this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

```
View::share('key', 'value');
```

If instead you want to remember a certain value to show on the next page, you can always use the session to "flash" data. The documentation has an article about that too:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data

Please note that you will need to re-inject these session data into the view, possibly by using the above "share" method on the View facade.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try it out and get back to you and inform you whether it worked or not.

Comment: And my issue is that I have a table which consists of user data. I have created a view in which I am able to view the user's name and on clicking on the name I am expecting to view the detailed info of that particular user.

Comment: Question is.. Is that detailed information a popup, a new page you visit or something completely different?

Comment: I want to show the detailed info on a new view. But information needs to be of the same user on whose hyperlinked name I clicked

Comment: A "view" in Laravel can be just another section on the page. In this case you can use `View::share()`.. In case your interpretation of view is another page use the last suggestion I gave.

Comment: Yep, I want to view the info on another page. So, I need to start with session first. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable to another view the same you do in your controller.

Let's say you have this method in your controller:

```
public function whatever()
{
    $someData = ...
    $otherData = ...

    return view('view', compact('someData', 'otherData));
}
```

And in your view:

```
<html>
   <h1>{{ $someData->text }}</h1>
   @include('otherView', ['otherData' => $otherData])
</html>
```

EDIT:

Note that, `otherData` will be available anyway in your included views. You don't need to pass it around. The above example is useful if you want to use a different alias to your variable.

Comment: Thank You for replying. Yup you are right, but can I pass the variable in the similar manner when I want to get my previous view data to be hyperlinked to the next view.

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly you want to pass data between different requests? That's a totally different matter. If you want to save data to be shared between requests you need to save it into a session.

Comment: Yup right. I have a table which consists of user data. I have created a view in which I am able to view the user's name and on clicking on the name I am expecting to view the detailed info the user. Could you please guide me through the issue? It would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, where you have your php vars you can use:

```
@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

and now in the 'view.name' you have variable $some contains 'data'

Comment: Thanks for replying mate. I want my view to be hyperlinked such that on my first view if there's a click it will be guided to the next view where I will show some related info from the first view..

Answer (score 0):

Its a long time ago I have created this functionality in which the variable is passed to multiple views.. Here is the code

```
View::composer('admin.layouts.navbar', function($view){
    $view->with('key', 12);
});
```

You can paste this code inside `routes.php` file

Here layout file is `/resources/views/admin/layout/navbar` and variable name is `$key` and it can be accessed in navbar view like

```
{{$key}}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying mate. But my data is never gonna be constant. o/p of the second view will be in accord to the first view o/p.